# CSS :first and :last-of-sequence pseudo-selectors like?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I need select some nodes in sequences via CSS. Is basically something like `.button:first-of-sequence`. Currently it doesn't exists, so I'm searching for an alternative method. See this case:

```
<div class="paginator-widget">
    <div class="page">First</div>
    <div class="page">Previous</div>
    <div class="separator"></div>
    <div class="page">1</div>
    <div class="page">2</div>
    <div class="page">3</div>
    <div class="page">4</div>
    <div class="separator"></div>
    <div class="page">Next</div>
    <div class="page">Last</div>
</div>
```

It's a paginator, and I need style each group of `.page` turning the `first-of-sequence` left border rounded, the `middle-sequence` (default) without border rounded and the `last-of-sequence` right border rounded (note that `.separator` breaks the sequences). Something like:

```
.page { background-color: black; color: white; }
.page:first-of-sequence { border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px; }
.page:last-of-sequence { border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0; }
```

Is it possible with *pure CSS*, or I need specify a new class to match this specific elements? ([like this example](http://jsfiddle.net/J3h4w/))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing like that exists, but you can use containing elements to achieve the same result.

HTML:

```
<div class="paginator-widget">
    <section>
        <div class="page">First</div>
        <div class="page">Previous</div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <div class="page">1</div>
        <div class="page">2</div>
        <div class="page">3</div>
        <div class="page">4</div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <div class="page">Next</div>
        <div class="page">Last</div>
    </section>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.page { background-color: black; color: white; }
section div:first-child { border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px; }
section div:last-child { border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0; }
```

**[jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/S7DE9/)**

Comment: I guess that it solve my problem and is a good general solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use sibling combinators to simulate `:first-of-sequence`, but not `:last-of-sequence`.

For example, even if the only elements in your parent element were `.page` and `.separator`, you could match `.page:first-of-sequence` using `.page:first-child, .separator + .page`, but you wouldn't be able to select `.page` elements directly preceding a `.separator`. That's because [CSS doesn't provide a previous sibling selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/css-previous-sibling-selector).

This is as far as you could go in replicating those selectors with pure CSS:

```
.page { background-color: black; color: white; }
.page:first-child, .separator + .page { border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px; }
.page:last-child { border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0; }
```

You can see in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/J3h4w/2) that the page 4 link doesn't have rounded corners like it's supposed to.

However, in your specific case, if you can rely on the first, second, second last and last elements being your first-previous and next-last pagination links, [you could simply use combinations of `:nth-child()` and `:nth-last-child()`](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/J3h4w/6):

```
.page { background-color: black; color: white; }

/* [First], [Next], [1] */
.page:first-child, .page:nth-last-child(2), .page:nth-child(4) { border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px; }

/* [Last], [Previous], [4] (or whatever ends up being the last page number) */
.page:last-child, .page:nth-child(2), .page:nth-last-child(4) { border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0; }
```

Notes:

- `:nth-child(3)` and `:nth-last-child(3)` are `.separator` elements, so we skip those and count to 4 instead.
- I think Chrome has a bug with `:nth-last-child()` which may force you to have to use `:nth-last-of-type()` instead, but I don't know if that's been fixed yet.

If all of this is too complex, the simplest alternative would be to group your end links (first-previous, next-last) and your page number links into their own parent elements separately if possible, which makes it easy for you to just target `.page:first-child` and `.page:last-child`, as [Lochlan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20916998/css-first-and-last-of-sequence-pseudo-selectors-like/20917116#20917116) shows.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
.page:first-child { border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px; }
.page:last-child { border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0; }
```

and verify it with [compatibility chart.](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/)

:first-child is supported IE9 properly, and IE7 and IE8 sort of (see chart).

:last-child is supported by IE9+ only.

Both of them are supported well by the good browsers.

You can also use `nth-child(even)` AND `nth-child(odd)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a pseudo selector available in css3 for first and last elements.
You can do something like this:

```
.page:first-child {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
.page:last-child {
   border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
```

And the nth-child pseudo selector for select elements using the index.
for example:

```
.page:nth-child(2){
 /* your custom style for second element */
}
```

Keep in mind, all css3 pseudo selectors don't work in old browsers, if you want compatibility, you should use classes for your particular elements.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by `:first-child, :last-child, :nth-child`

```
.paginator-widget div.page:first-child, 
.paginator-widget div.page:nth-child(4), 
.paginator-widget div.page:nth-child(9){
    padding-left: 15px;
    border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}

.paginator-widget div.page:last-child, 
.paginator-widget div.page:nth-child(2), 
.paginator-widget div.page:nth-child(7){
    border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;    
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

**[updated jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/J3h4w/5/)**